# Submit Devise username with all forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, controller

I have a Rails 4 app using Devise, CanCan and Bootstrap on a legacy PostgreSQL database. Almost all of my tables have a 'moduser' column along with my modtime and created_at columns (as mentioned the db is legacy hence the deviation from Rails conventions).

The intention is to record the username of the last user to modify a record (it can be null). For all models (tables) that have the moduser column I would like the forms to automatically submit the Devise username (ie current_user.username) along with the other parameters without the user having to enter it in a text field with `:value => current_user.username`.

I could perhaps use an `input type="hidden"` element for moduser in every _form.html.erb but that doesn't feel very DRY to me.

How can I implement it in a DRY manner so that every form submits current_user.username and maps it to the moduser column of a table if it exists?

**UPDATE**

I like the idea of the controller Concern so I tried to implement it but unfortunately I am stuck on how the pieces fit together. Here's my Concern:

```
module ModUpdateable extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
   after_update :update_moduser
   after_create :update_moduser
  end

  def update_moduser
    update(moduser: current_user.username)
  end
end
```

I am just trying this out on my CountriesController so I add `include ModUpdateable` to the top of the controller code, right before my `before_filter :authenticate_user!` line.

When I spin up my puma server I get a Routing Error

> undefined method `after_update' for CountriesController:Class
>   app/controllers/concerns/mod_updateable.rb:4:in`block in '
>   app/controllers/countries_controller.rb:2:in `include'
>   app/controllers/countries_controller.rb:2:in`'
>   app/controllers/countries_controller.rb:1:in `

Am I missing something?

I also suspect that the `update_moduser` method will throw the next exception; how do I access the `@country` instance variable in the `create` and `update` methods of the CountriesController? (@country is just an example; this will have to apply to all of my resources)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making it a form field you can also add the information to the `params` hash in the controller:

```
@item.update(item_params.merge(moduser: current_user.username, modtime: Time.now))
```

Or you could write a `Concern` for the models that have these attributes. The concern should define an `after_update` filter that sets `moduser` and `modtime` on every update. This is the most DRY solution.

Comment: This is a great way to do it.

Comment: I really like the idea of the Concern but am not advanced enough to know how to do this. I tried to implement something but it's not quite right. I've updated the post with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you handle it in controller? 
The solutions are many but i can not really understand how your app works.